# PHP Expected transport is "https" but incoming transport found : "http"

Tags: php, https

someone know how to solve the error(see headline)?

my code:

```
    $wsdl = "https://...";
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>true, 'login'=>"test",'password'=>"test",
      'local_cert' => "C:\xampp1.8.2-2\tomcat\conf\.cer",
     'passphrase' => "test"));

$result = $client->findUser($params);
```

Comment: This error occurs because you don't have the openssl extension enabled in your PHP build. The `https` stream wrapper relies on *ext/openssl* to function. If you don't have it, this is why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes with a backslash for the value of your `local_cert`

Do like this

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>true, 'login'=>"test",'password'=>"test",
    'local_cert' => "C:\\xampp1.8.2-2\\tomcat\\conf\\.cer",
    'passphrase' => "test"));
```